# How to make pdf read only in itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

My code follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\SF_Users.pdf");
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            Rectangle psize = reader.getPageSize(1);
            Document document = new Document(psize);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("D:\\new.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte pdf = writer.getDirectContent();
            document.newPage();
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
            pdf.addTemplate(page, .5f, 0, 0, .5f, 60, 120);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception de) {
        }
    }
```

Here i can able to read pdf while writting i want make it read only

Thank You

Comment: *"i want make it read only"* Anything which you can do to a PDF can be undone by a power user with a machine they control, including overriding 'no print' and 'read only' flags.

Comment: Yes i agree with you , you are talking about adminstrator the power user in much better words , but i want give them a pdf file which should be read only and should not allowd to print, in that case i will not allow them to select a file i do sending them a file, even they dont where woulb be the file location

Comment: *"even they dont where woulb be the file location"* Why would the power user not know or not be able to find out?

Comment: Power user know the file location , but other dont want know they are only can read nothing they should not do

Comment: Are you sure you want to go down the DRM way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `PdfEncryptionSettings` API?

> The open permissions for the document can be AllowPrinting, AllowModifyContents, AllowCopy, AllowModifyAnnotations, AllowFillIn, AllowScreenReaders, AllowAssembly and AllowDegradedPrinting.