# Disable commenting on PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrobat, itextpdf

I am using iText 2.1.7 for creating read-only PDF. I am using acrofields to set the content on the form. The PDF generated is read-only, any of the form fields are not editable.

The issue I am having is client doesn't want user to even add comments/ sticky notes from tool bar. Can anyone please suggest how I can disable commenting from tools on PDF using iText 2.1.7.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662424/how-to-make-pdf-read-only-in-itext

Comment: Please read the answer to [Generate pdf file in Secured mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466710/). It lists all the possible permissions that you can use with the `setEncryption()` method. Also tell your client that he should use iText 2.1.7 because of [legal and technical issues](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially) and ask him to sign a paper so that he doesn't sue you when he finds out you've been introducing an IP liability into his source base.

Comment: Thanks both bruno & rafael, it did help.